# Persistence of permanent node on Jenkins running as container kubernetes

Tags: jenkins, containers

I am facing an issue where jenkins running on kubernetes looses permanent node added manually after jenkins pod restarts. Is there a way to persist jenkins node added manually during pod restart. Any way we can persist permanant node in jenkins.

Comment: I hope you are using persistent volume for your Jenkins pod? Can you confirm? Also, how have you deployed Jenkins; Is it via JCasC?

Comment: Yes we are using persistent volumes and JCasC is used for deployment. But nodes are added manually after the deployment, which gets lost after deployment.

Answer (score 0):

When you adding new agents to Jenkins, it is changing main jenkins' config.

To save it's state after restarting - use persistent volume for master.

But if you are using jenkins in kubernetes - there is no need to add agents manually. Just configure pod templates and call them via labels.